# Spring Resource Assembler throwing NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-hateoas

I am using ResourceAssemblerSupport from spring-hateoas in a spring boot Application

I have created the assembler like below:

```
public class MemberResourceAssembler extends ResourceAssemblerSupport<Member, MemberResource>{

    public MemberResourceAssembler(Class<?> controllerClass, Class<MemberResource> resourceType) {
        super(controllerClass, resourceType);
    }
    @Override
    public MemberResource toResource(Member member) {
        MemberResource memberResource=new MemberResource();
        memberResource.setStatus(member.getStatus());
        memberResource.setHeight(member.getHeight());
        memberResource.setIs_veg(member.getIs_veg());
        memberResource.setRace(member.getRace());
        memberResource.setWeight(member.getWeight());
        return memberResource;
    }

}
```

And the reource class as below:

```
public class MemberResource extends ResourceSupport implements Serializable{
//relevant code here
}
```

The domain class is as below:

```
@Document(collection="Member")
public class Member {
//relevant code here
}
```

The repository class is as below:

```
public interface MemberRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Member,Integer> {

    Page<Member> findByStatusContainsIgnoreCase(@Param("q") String status, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Now I am trying to use in my controller as below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/members")
public class MemberController {
     @Autowired
    private MemberRepository memberRepository;

     @Autowired
    private MemberResourceAssembler assembler;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public PagedResources<MemberResource> search(@RequestParam("status") String status, @PageableDefault Pageable pageable,
            PagedResourcesAssembler<Member> pagedAssembler) {
         Page<Member> members = memberRepository.findByStatusContainsIgnoreCase(status, pageable);
         return pagedAssembler.toResource(members, assembler);   
    }

}
```

I am getting below exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.sg.resources.MemberResourceAssembler] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Using spring-hateoas version 0.19.0.RELEASE.All the dependencies are coming through starters of Spring Boot 1.3.0.RELEASE

There is a spring boot Application class in the parent package of the Controller class.The Autowire annotation on the repository  is working properly.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense that the `MemberResourceAssembler` constructor expects arguments in the first place.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I added a bean definition in the Application.class which solved the issue

```
    @SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public MemberResourceAssembler memberResourceAssembler() {
        return new MemberResourceAssembler(MemberController.class, MemberResource.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `MemberResourceAssembler` should be annotated as `@Component` to make it available for autowiring.

Comment: Adding @Component gives me an exception saying "No default constructor found" and when I try to add a default constructor compiler gives me "Implicit super constructor ResourceAssemblerSupport<Member,MemberResource>() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor"

Comment: After you added the `@Component` annotation, Spring actually tried to instantiate your class for the frist time, so that was ok. After that you added a default constructor, that was also ok. The last step should have been to invoke the super constructor from your own default constructor with the parameters you already had: `super(MemberController.class, MemberResource.class);`